# Difference between Load address, relocate address, board data, board relocate address after uncompressing linux kernel

Tags: bootloader, powerpc

I am trying to understand the code after uncompressing linux kernel from board, it is showing as:

```
DRAM OK

Autoboot in 2 seconds.
ESC to abort, SPACE or ENTER to go.

loaded at:     FF900000 FFB571DC
relocated to:  00400000 006571DC
board data at: 00655120 0065515C
relocated to:  004050CC 00405108
zimage at:     00405AC4 004BD747
initrd at:     004BE000 00654080
avail ram:     00658000 00F00000
```

What is meaning of each value, these addresses are part of RAM?
if so why they have to relocate inside ram itself?

I want to load zImage and ramdisk addresses in other locations, is this possible, without giving any relocation addresses?
Explain me in detail or please add link for reference to understand the same.

Comment: This is actually the question about your bootloader (PlanetCore, isn't it?), not about Linux kernel.

Comment: yes, that is true, thank you for modifying the question.